# How to get the CommandArgument of an ImageButton inside a Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, imagebutton, asp.net-2.0, commandargument

I have a repeater which structured like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RpAccBind" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RpAccBind_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="acsryRow" runat="server">
            <td data-th="Product">
                <div class="prodImgMain">
                    <img src="../instrumentimages/<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>" alt="<%# Eval("ProductName")%>" />
                </div>
            </td>

            <td data-th="Description">
                <div class="prodDescriptionContainer">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="prdRow"><%# Eval("ProductName") %></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="quantityIconWrap form-group">
                    <span class="number-wrapper">

                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' ID="txtqty" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" size="3" Width="50" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" OnTextChanged="txtQtyTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

                    </span>
                    <span>

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkAscRemove" runat="server" class="btn" OnClick="lnkRemoveClick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId")%>' ImageUrl="../images/deleteIcon.png"></asp:ImageButton>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td data-th="Amount" style="padding-right: 5%;">
                <div class="amountColMain">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span><strong><span id="litConPrice" runat="server">$<%# Eval("ConsumerPrice") %></span></strong></span></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now, whenever the txtQty is 0, i want to have the productid in respect of the imagebutton clicked. Right Now, i am using something like

```
long productId = Convert.ToInt64(((ImageButton)((RepeaterItem)txtQty.Parent).FindControl("lnkAscRemove")).CommandArgument);
```

It is giving me an error of unable to cast **HtmlTableCell** to **RepeaterItem**

Any Kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you trying this ? txtQty.Parent is a div not repeater item, that's why you got that error

Answer (score 2):

To use `CommandName` and `CommandArgument`, you need to use a `Command` event, not a `Click`.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lnkAscRemove" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkAscRemove_Command"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId")%>'
```

Code behind

```
protected void lnkAscRemove_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

**Update**

If you want to get the `ProductId` from a TextBox, you could add it as a custom property and then read it in code behind.

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' ID="txtqty" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    OnTextChanged="txtqty_TextChanged" ProductId='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind

```
protected void txtqty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    Label1.Text = tb.Attributes["ProductId"];
}
```

Comment: No, but there are other ways. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Repeater has an ItemCommand that watches for button events inside the Repeater elements. The CommandName and CommandArgument is passed to the event.

Also of importance is the Item which represents the Repeater Item that the button was clicked in. Then you can use the FindControls method to find related server controls object for the same RepeaterItem in which the button was clicked.

```
protected void MyRepeater_ItemCommand(Object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.CommandName == "edit") {
       SetEditorTo(e.CommandArgument);
   }
   RepeaterItem row = e.Item;
   Textbox tQty = row.FindControls("txtqty");
}
```